# Keep center div inside other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center the hover div `class="opa"` with a button, without care the height or width the div `class="hello"` because the templates have diferents sizes.

I was trying with `left:50% , top 50%, position:absolute;` but i can't achieve center the button.

This is my code:

```css
.cosa {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.hello:hover .cosa {
    display: block;
}

.canceled {
    background-color: #3F3736;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 15px!important;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 280px!important;
    width: 210px;
    margin-top: 25px!important;
    font-weight: 70!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
      <div class="opa">
      <span id="cancel" class="pull-right canceled cprev previews cosa" ng-click="editing(); addDataSign();"><button type="button">CHANGE TEMPLATE</button></span></div>
     <div class="tdescrip ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding" ng-model="opened.HTML" editor="" data-ng-bind-html="opened.template">            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">        <title>Template signature</title>                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size:11px; font-family: Arial; line-height: 17px;" width="100%">            <tbody><tr>                <td valign="top" style="background-color:#f6f7f8; padding: 10px; border-right-width:2px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color:#ff7f00 " width="50%">                    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#29363f; font-weight: bold ">XXXXX</span><br><br>                    XXXXXXXXXX<br>                    mobile: XXXXXXXXXXX<br>                    <span style="color:#009ee0"></span>                </td>                <td valign="top" style="background-color:#d1d7db; padding: 10px; padding-left: 20px" width="50%">                    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#29363f ;font-weight: bold"></span><br><br>                   XXXXXXX<br>                                        <span style="color:#009ee0"></span>                </td>            </tr>            <tr>                <td colspan="2">                    <p style="font-size:8px; font-family:Verdana; color:#959595; line-height: 10px;"></p>                </td>            </tr>        </tbody></table>    </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: use this site http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.hello {
    position: relative;
}
.opa {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
        -ms-transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
            transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    position: absolute;
}
```